# How to build a dynamic query based on dropdown option?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

EDITED:

SQL

```
$valuefromjs = $_REQUEST['var'];
$result6 = "SELECT DISTINCT $valuefromjs FROM persons ORDER BY $valuefromjs ASC";
$result7 = mysql_query($result6);
$num = mysql_num_rows($result7);  

$dataRanges[0] = array('dataRanges');       
        for ($i=1; $i<($num+1); $i++)
        {
        $dataRanges[$i] = array( (int) mysql_result($result7, $i-1) );
        }

echo json_encode($dataRanges);
```

HTML

```
<select id="combo2" class="combo" data-index="2"></select>
```

jQuery

```
$('#1combo').on('change', function () {
var jsonVar = $.ajax({
url : "visits/comboquery.php?var="+$(this).val(), 
dataType: "json",
async: false,
success: function(response) {
}
}).responseText;
for (var i=1; i<objVar.length;i++)
    {
    $('#combo2').html("<option value="+objVar[i]+">"+objVar[i]+"</option>");
    }
});
```

QUESTION:

I have an array with query results. Now i need that results be the combo2 options, what is wrong?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: And please use descriptive titles and not a set of tags

Comment: @KingCrunch, done. About the question, it could be done this way? The variable should change everytime that combo1 option is changed, without reload page or submit.

Comment: @njk, thanks for the advide, ill serious look for it. But atm i need help to figure this out. What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding the choice from combo1 will define which query to run for building combo2.

The issue: your PHP for building the combo2 is parsed at the server side i.e. the PHP code is always finished executing by the time the page reaches the user's browser and your javascript begins to execute.

If you have a finite set of possible queries that can generate the seconds combo (which should be the case since combo1 has a finite number of options), you can create all of them, each with a different id, and maintain them hidden (css "display: none").

```
<select id="firstCombo2" class="combo2">
    ...
</select>
<select id="secondCombo2" class="combo2">
    ...
</select>
```

etc.

Now, when the user makes a selection from combo1, you can decide which one of the hidden combo2's you are going to display (css "display: block").

```
$('select#combo1).on("change", function(){
    $('select.combo2').css('display','none'); //hide all combo2's
    if($(this).val()=='Opt1'){
            $('select#firstCombo2').css('display','block');
    }else if($(this).val()=='Opt2'){
            $('select#secondCombo2').css('display','block');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use AJAX in order to solve your problem.
on combo1 onChange call an AJAX call to your server and send selected value of combo1.
Then in your php code run query with value received from AJAX request and construct a new combo box with options in string and echo back that string. You can use that AJAX response to populate new combo2.